# Resizing Text When Window Resizes Python/Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a Python / Kivy application I am creating, and I am trying to make the text resize when the window resizes. I've looked it up a bit but I haven't found anything that works exactly as I expect it to. I figured I'd bind on_resize to a function that resizes the text, but I get a lot of errors. This the relevant code.

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.font_size = 25

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        def win_cb(window, width, height):
            new_size = sqrt(width**2 + height**2)/40.6
            MainScreen().font_size = new_size
        Window.bind(on_resize=win_cb)
```

I should also mention that in a .kv file I have something like this

```
<MainScreen>:
    Label:
        text: "Text here"
        pos_hint: {"x": -0.15, "y": 0.05}
        font_size: root.font_size*80/25
```

On runtime it works fine, but when I resize the window I get a huge column of errors, evidently related to MainScreen not having an attribute font_size.

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1649,     in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap)
   File "main.kv", line 46, in <module>
     font_size: root.font_size
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 19, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__ (kivy/weakproxy.c:1101)
 AttributeError: 'MainScreen' object has no attribute 'font_size'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 2011, in _apply_rule
 value, rule, rctx['ids'])
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1654, in create_handler
 cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.BuilderException: Parser: File "main.kv", line 46:
 ...
      44:       text: "Simplify Fraction"
      45:       pos_hint: {"right": 1, "top":0.2}
 >>   46:       font_size: root.font_size
      47:
      48:
 ...
 AttributeError: 'MainScreen' object has no attribute 'font_size'
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1649, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap)
   File "main.kv", line 46, in <module>
     font_size: root.font_size
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 19, in     kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__ (kivy/weakproxy.c:1101)


 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/onehitfinish/Downloads/Gregulator Files/test.py", line 88, in <module>
     MainApp().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 824, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 487, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 525, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 290, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/base.py", line 327, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 483, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 615, in _process_events
     event.tick(self._last_tick, remove)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 374, in tick
     ret = callback(self._dt)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 188, in create_window
     super(WindowSDL, self).create_window()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 779, in create_window
     self.dispatch('on_resize', *self.system_size)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 695, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:6970)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1168, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:12154)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1092, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy/_event.c:11729)
   File "/home/onehitfinish/Downloads/Gregulator Files/test.py", line 81, in win_cb
     MainScreen().font_size = new_size
   File "/home/onehitfinish/Downloads/Gregulator Files/test.py", line 41, in __init__
     super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 255, in __init__
     super(RelativeLayout, self).__init__(**kw)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 66, in __init__
     super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 66, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 271, in __init__
     Builder.apply(self)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1872, in apply
     self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 2018, in _apply_rule
 e), cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.BuilderException: Parser: File "main.kv", line 46:
 ...
      44:       text: "Simplify Fraction"
      45:       pos_hint: {"right": 1, "top":0.2}
 >>   46:       font_size: root.font_size
      47:
      48:
 ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "main.kv", line 46:
 ...
      44:       text: "Simplify Fraction"
      45:       pos_hint: {"right": 1, "top":0.2}
 >>   46:       font_size: root.font_size
      47:
      48:
 ...
 AttributeError: 'MainScreen' object has no attribute 'font_size'
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1649, in  create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap)
   File "main.kv", line 46, in <module>
     font_size: root.font_size
   File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 19, in     kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__ (kivy/weakproxy.c:1101)

   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 2011, in _apply_rule
value, rule, rctx['ids'])
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1654, in create_handler
 cause=tb)
```

Any help on fixing this, or perhaps suggesting an alternate way of doing this as I am very new to Kivy would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining **font_size** as a `NumericProperty` in **MainScreen**:

```
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class MainScreen(Screen):

    font_size = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.font_size = 25
```

Comment: Now it doesn't break or anything when I resize the window, but it doesn't seem to change MainScreen().font_size in the win_cb function. I'm not sure if MainScreen() actually references a completely new instance or something, therefore defaulting it right back to 25, but when I have code like
    def win_cb(window, width, height):
           new_size = sqrt(width**2 + height**2)/40.6
           print(new_size)
           MainScreen().font_size = new_size
           print(MainScreen().font_size)
it prints something like

37.94142906643079
25
37.94142906643079
25

Any ideas?

Comment: @Onehitfinish  font_size: root.font_size*80/25 seems a bit pointless. Seems like one of those numbers should be a float, as 80/25 will just be 3

Comment: @Onehitfinish Also, I'm pretty sure that MainScreen().font_size = new_size does create a new MainScreen instance. Only thing is, the instance isn't even being saved into a variable or anything, so probably just gets destroyed when win_cb returns. Also, why have you defined win_cb inside the build method?

Comment: I feel like that's something I probably should have done. Basically the reason I put it in the MainApp was because https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/789 has it in it's class that inherits from App, so I figured that's like standard. As I said I'm pretty new to Kivy in general. Do you think pasting the relevant code into the class would basically work (with small adjustments such as replacing MainScreen() with self perhpaps), or should I do this in a different way?